# Regular Expressions Java

Tags: java, regex, swing

I have an JTextField that takes an IP address, and a JTextField that takes a username using Email. How can I read a JTextField once I click submit, and have it tell me if it is the correct format in a showMessageDialog?

```
public static boolean isValidIP(String iField)
{
    return iField.matches("^(\\d{1,3})\\.(\\d{1,3})\\.(\\d{1,3})\\.(\\d{1,3})$");     
}
public static boolean isValidUser(String uField)
{
    return uField.matches("^[_A-Za-z0-9-\\\\+]+(\\\\.[_A-Za-z0-9-]+)*\n" +
    "@[A-Za-z0-9-]+(\\\\.[A-Za-z0-9]+)*(\\\\.[A-Za-z]{2,})$");
}

sButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener()
    {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae)
        {

            iField.getText();
            uField.getText();

        }
    });
```

Comment: [IP address validation](https://www.google.com/search?q=site%3Astackoverflow.com+java&oq=site&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8#q=site:stackoverflow.com+java+validate+ip+address+string) and [EMail address validation](https://www.google.com/search?q=site%3Astackoverflow.com+java&oq=site&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8#q=site:stackoverflow.com+java+validate+email+address+string). Did you search this problem first before asking?

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels Yes, but I am not sure how to read it when I click the submit button.. I can't find how to do that.

Comment: You should use Pattern.compile("anyregex"), instead of  compile regex dynamically every time by using String.matches("anyregex)

Comment: What?  IPv6 addresses are IP addresses too! :)

Comment: Pattern and Matcher work great.. I just didn't want to use it this go around.. Thanks for the tip!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this :

```
sButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener()
{
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae)
    {

        String ip = iField.getText();
        String uf = uField.getText();
       //pass it through the method to validate it
        if(isValidUser(uf))
       JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(yourFrameName, "your message.");
        if(isValidIP(ip))
       JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(yourFrameName, "your message.");

    }
});
```

Comment: Perfect! You're awesome!